# Javascript Code that popups and asks user to set website as homepage

Tags: javascript, popup

I need a javascript code for this function.

When a user visits the website , a window pops up with a message asking the user to set a website as HOME PAGE for their browser.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and where you are stuck or you won't get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok here is the script you need:

```
<a href="#" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';this.setHomePage('http://www.yoursite.com');">Set as homepage</a>
```

for a button use this code:

```
<button onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';this.setHomePage('http://www.yoursite.com');">Set as homepage</button>
```

But dont put it in a code where it popsup every time a user visits the page. It is a bad practice.